# how to generic type property

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a type like enum that would allow me to merge these variable into one

```
    private string StringPropertie;
    private int IntPropertie;
    private float floatPropertie;
    private DateTime DatetimePropertie;
    private bool boolPropertie;
```

to something has follow.

```
private enumtype property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use structure

```
public struct MyStruct
    {
        public string StringPropertie;
        public int IntPropertie;
        public float floatPropertie;
        public DateTime DatetimePropertie;
        public bool boolPropertie;
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
              MyStruct property ;
              //...


              string str = property.StringPropertie;

        }
   }
```

Comment: how would it know to choose between int and string

Comment: @Jseb that's part of the editor & compiler, not yours.

Comment: Don't use mutable structs! A `class` is better suited if you feel that you need a mutable data type.

Comment: @Ron Beyer It is up to the user to see what he needs. Sometimes a class, and sometimes a structure. With the difference that we know between these two entities. a structure may be stacked so that a class is not.

Comment: Mutable structs are almost always a bad idea, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031(v=vs.110).aspx where even Microsoft says to avoid mutable structs.

Comment: @AtmaneELBOUACHRI If the OP is at the level of asking how to define a class/struct, it's almost certain they should be using class.